# Turn off force UTF8 encoding in pyspark

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a python code like below to read data from Oracle using pyspark.

```
tableDF = spark.read \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
            .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + hostid + ".dev.com:1521/" + databaseinstance) \
            .option("dbtable", sqlstring) \
            .option("numPartitions", 1) \
            .option("fetchsize", fetchsize) \
            .option("user", contextname) \
            .option("password", contextname) \
            .load() \
```

The **database source charset is US7ASCII** but since there is no validation on loading data into Oracle it contains data with various encoding charsets. **In a nut shell, even though DB charset is US7ASCII it has data with mixed encodings of UTF8, ISO-8859-1 in its columns.**

Am able to read data successfully from Oracle into the dataframe without any issues but the data got collapsed because of the force encoding to UTF-8 by pyspark which results in some of my data have the UTF-8 replacement character such as ***EFBFA2EFBE80EFBE93*** which is not recognizable properly due to the presence of Unicode character E2 80 93 in the columns which contain source charset as US7ASCII

The field's type is `varchar`. The stored value is `–`, the [en dash character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). Instead of the character, the bytes `0xE2 0x80 0x93` are returned, which are translated to `???`.

Calling `DUMP(NAME,'1016')` on a row whose `NAME` value is

```
CLINIC – NORTH
```

Returns :

> Typ=1 Len=69 CharacterSet=US7ASCII: 
>   43,4f,52,41,20,**e2,80,93**,20,4e,4f,52,54,48,

So, am looking to simply read data from Oracle without any encoding to my data. Basically, I dont want any forced encoding to the data am retrieving. I simply want them in the way it was stored in Oracle.

Is there a way to turn OFF this default encoding to UTF-8 by pyspark?
or 
How can I make JDBC or PYTHON drivers to treat those characters as such in whatever encoding form they are in?

***As I already mentioned since my DB contains mixed encoding charsets forcing any particular encoding like UTF8/US-ASCII/ISO-8859-1 will work for some data but not for the others and thats why i need a way to not enforce any encoding at all.***

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The *Unicode* replacement character appears when you try to read *non*-Unicode text using the wrong codepage. Turning off the UTF8 conversion won't make the problem go away, the codepage used will still be wrong. How are is the text stored in *Oracle*? What is the type's column? Unless it's one of the Unicode types, you'd have to read it using the correct codepage.

Comment: In any case, Spark is built on the JVM whose strings are Unicode, specifically UTF16. The problem occured in the JDBC driver itself, not Spark.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, thats right. When ever the underlying characters stored in Oracle are not UTF8 compatible the conversion becomes messy. Even though the charset in Oracle is of US7ASCII since we are not doing any validation while loading data into Oracle we cant guarantee all the underlying data are of US7ASCII as oracle can store extended ASCIIs as well in its column. So, here there are 2 approaches, either I need to identify the underlying encoding properly or do not encode at all. Since in my case the underlying data can have whatever encoding it will be better to not encode at all

Comment: So, is there any config that can be passed to the JDBC driver via pyspark to avoid this forceful encoding?

Comment: There's no forceful encoding, or rather *every* Java/JVM application, including Spark, use Unicode. The problem is an incorrect character set. The JDBC driver would work otherwise. You'll have to find out where the error occurs. Check the stored text, the column collations, the actual content. What are the column types? Is the text *already* mangled in the database perhaps? There wouldn't be any issue if The Oracle driver would be able to convert `varchar` values using the correct codepage which suggests the text may be stored using the wrong codepage

Comment: How did you install the JDBC driver? [The docs suggest](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/global.htm#JJDBC28644) that you need to add the orai18n.jar package to support codepages other than UTF8, US-ASCII and Latin. [So do the OTA4H docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E65728_01/doc.43/e65665/GUID-C2A509A4-34CB-4B58-AC55-6CCCE51163A8.htm#BIGUG76783)

Comment: I will check for this orai18n.jar driver and install it if its not there and test

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added the orai18n.jar as you suggested in my classpath **parunkarthick$ echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/parunkarthick/Downloads/ojdbc8.jar:/Users/parunkarthick/Downloads/orai18n.jar** but still the same. The data does not changed and still has invalid UTF chars

Comment: I think since the data stored in oracle itself is not of US7SACII and when spark try to do utf8 encode from us7ascii(because the charset is us7ascii) the conversion got messy. And thats why am looking for a way to not encode at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have verified that the data in the Dataframe is unchanged and there is no conversion happening. However, when am writing to a file as csv **tableDF.write.csv(filepath, mode='append', compression='gzip', escape='"')** because of the default encoding UTF-8 some characters become messed up. Is there a way to avoid this encoding when writing into a file?

Comment: That's not the problem. Once again the problem is that whatever code or application is trying to read the output, *doesn't* use UTF8. Change it so it uses UTF8, or change the machine's locale to use UTF8 (eg `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`). Otherwise you'll have to find what the correct character set is and hard-code the character set through the `encoding` parameter of `write.csv`. This will fail once again though if you try to process text from a different codepage

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In my case the hex code that got replaced is E28093 which is a Unicode character but that still got replaced with replacement character. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

Comment: You mean `–` ? SO is an ASP.NET and the data is saved in Unicode (mvarchar) fields in SQL Server. This page uses UTF8 (like all web pages) and yet, you can read the en dash just fine. There's nothing wrong with UTF8. The problem may be the SQL query itself or the use of ASCII instead of Unicode fields in the database

Comment: Yes thats the character causing the issue. Even though it is valid utf8 when reading from oracle using pyspark it replaced with replacement character

Comment: Post the SQL query and the table schema. Without them you're asking people to guess. Oracle has no problems with Unicode. Bad text types or bad collations can easily cause such problems

Comment: BTW that character is most definitely *not* in the US-ASCII codepage. UTF8 and US-ASCII bytes are *identical* by design. UTF8 uses the same bytes as US-ASCII in the 0x00-0x7F range

Comment: It is just a varchar column and am reading all the columns from the table. The sqlstring from the above question represents just "select * from that_table". Source charset of oracle is US7ASCII

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204395/discussion-between-arunb2w-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: `It is just a varchar column` there's nothing "just" about a varchar column. That's a single-byte text type that's *guaranteed* to lose text that doesn't match its collation

Comment: Actually it is varchar2. You mean to change that to nvarchar2 or something?

Comment: Check [Implementing a Unicode Solution in the Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch6unicode.htm#CACHCAHF). You need to either create the database with the `AL32UTF8` character set from the start or use `nvarchar2` for the fields that need Unicode data

Comment: Database contains variety of tables with huge volume of records. Recreating them is not an option for me. Thats why looking to see if there is a way to avoid this kind of conversion being happened while reading from Oracle

Comment: The conversion happened when the data was stored using the wrong character set. It's not Python's fault or PySpark's. The JDBC driver would convert the characters to UTF8 *correctly* if they were stored using the database's or column's character set. Or it could be due to some string manipulations in the SQL query, which you still haven't posted

Comment: No thats not happened here. In Oracle when i see the dump of the column using dump(column, '1016') am able to see the character corresponding to E28093 retained as such and the hex also shows the same.

Comment: See this example: NAME
DUMP(NAME,'1016')
CORA REHABILITATION CLINIC **–** NORTH TAMPA (CORA HEALTH SERVICES INC)
Typ=1 Len=69 CharacterSet=US7ASCII: 43,4f,52,41,20,52,45,48,41,42,49,4c,49,54,41,54,49,4f,4e,20,43,4c,49,4e,49,43,20,**e2,80,93**,20,4e,4f,52,54,48,20,54,41,4d,50,41,20,28,43,4f,52,41,20,48,45,41,4c,54,48,20,53,45,52,56,49,43,45,53,20,49,4e,43,29

Comment: So fix the `CharacterSet` to something that can actually hold those strings, eg `AL32UTF8 `. That's the bug. The conversion is made by the JDBC driver, because the database *explicitly says* that those values should be treated as 7-bit ASCII, **NOT** UTF8. It may be a nuisance, but *that's* the actual bug that needs to be fixed. Python never even sees those bytes. It sees the *characters* that correspond to those bytes

Comment: And you still haven't updated the question with the necessary information - table schema, character sets, contents

Comment: In fact, what you need is the *exact opposite* of what you asked. JDBC is *already* returning those *UTF8* characters as *US7ASCII* bytes - it doesn't try to convert them. You need to make it convert the US7ASCII bytes back to UTF8

Comment: Again, and again, and again, **post the table schema and query in the question itself**. You're **confusing** people that try to answer. You stored UTF8 text in a US-ASCII column. Write that in the question itself. What you *really* want is to force either JDBC or Python to treat US-ASCII as if it were UTF8. You don't ask that though, so people won't be able to tell you how to do it. I think you simply *can't* do that with the JDBC Thin driver, as it doesn't allow mapping when the field charset is US-ASCII

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the suggestion, will definitely update my question in a clearer way. One more thing is, this is one example in which UTF8 data stored in US-ASCII but there are other cases where some tables have other encodings such as ISO-8859-1 as well. Thats why i posted the question as try to avoid this force conversion in any way irrespective of what the underlying charset is

Comment: Updated the question. Basically as you mentioned i want to force either JDBC or Python to treat those underlying characters as such without any forceful encoding because this is one example where UTF8 is stored under ASCII but there are other tables/columns which has encoding in ISO-8859-1 as well. If i made JDBC or python to treat all those as UTF8 those other encoding chars in other columns will show up similar kind of problems and thats why i dont want any encoding to enforce by default. Please advise if you have any thoughts

Comment: There's no forceful encoding involved. That's the point. The UTF8 data was stored using the **wrong** encoding, as US-ASCII. The JDBC Thin driver performs *no* conversions when reading US-ASCII text. That's why you have a problem. Those three bytes were treated as 3 US-ASCII characters instead of one UTF8 character. You have a problem because you **don't** have any encoding conversions

Comment: Thoughts: I already explained the fix. Change the charset and load the data again. Or add a *new* column with the correct charset and copy the binary data. After that, it's only hacks, eg load the field as binary data and convert them using UTF8 on the client'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my idea works in your case, but I tried this:

`.option("encoding", "US-ASCII")`

And this should change the encoding.

---

Another idea would be to set the encoding globally if you use for example pyspark:

```
import sys 
reload(sys) #reload seems to be important, otherwise next step can break
sys.setdefaultencoding('us-ascii')
```

Comment: This *causes* the problem in the first place. Somewhere in the 47th comment the OP said the data comes from a table with US7ASCII character set and yet, contains an en-Dash stored using UTF8 encoding. JDBC returns the data as US-ASCII, which means that instead of a single en Dash, Python receives three characters. In essence, what the OP wants is the **exact opposite** of what the question asks. The OP actually wants to force JDBC to treat US-ASCII as if it were UTF8

Comment: Now I got it right. Thank you very much for the explanation. @PanagiotisKanavos